# USB Interfacing of TETRA device with microcontroller

Tags: usb, usb-host

I am trying to interface my TETRA device with the microcontroller using the USB interface. The microcontroller will act as a usb host while the TETRA will act as a USB device. I am using STM32F469I-DISCO development board. The microcontroller which I am using supports the USB interfacing too. Is it possible to have such kind of interfacing with this TETRA device? Please note , this TETRA device needs a specific USB driver (provided by the company) to install and run while connecting the TETRA device with the PC COM port, but now I want to connect it with the microcontroller development board. Does the development board can support only those USB devices which don't require a driver to run?

Comment: Which TETRA device? Which USB VID/PID it has to determine the driver? What kind of device it presents to the host? All USB devices need a driver. And the MCU must implement this driver to communicate, so in theory anything is possible.

Comment: This TETRA? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_Trunked_Radio Or this one? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neon_tetra

Comment: @Justme-- motorola TETRA (Terrestrial Trunked Radio)  USB device.

Comment: usbcdcacm\VID_xxxx&PID_xxxx&MI_00\7&119c8571&0&6_3f786bd_1_0000_00 (taken from the device manager)................. Its a communication device class (CDC)